# Which of the three matrices will the powers remain bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix},$ $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix},$ $C= \begin{pmatrix} 1.98 & .99\\ -.99 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Consider the powers $A^j, B^j, C^j, j=1,2,...$ for the three matrices.

For which of the three matrices will the powers remain bounded? For which of the three matrices will the powers converge to the zero matrix as $j\to\infty$?

I have for matrix A, that the eigenvalues are 1,1. For matrix B, I have that the eigenvalues are -i,+i. For matrix C, I have that the eigenvalues are .99,.99.

Matrix A has one jordan block and since $|\lambda|=1$, it is not bounded and it is going to infinity.

I am not sure about matrix B.

I can see from matlab that matrix C converges to the zero matrix, but I'm not sure how to show this by hand. Since $|\lambda|<1$ it is bounded.

I'm not entirely sure if I am correct, if not, how do I show which powers remain bounded and which converges to the zero matrix?

Comment: For $B$, write out the first few powers, notice the pattern, make your conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A$, as you say that Jordan form is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. So the Jordan form of $A^n$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

The matrix $B$ satisfies $B^2=-I$. So $B^{2n}=(-1)^nI$, $B^{2n+1}=(-1)^nB$.

For $C$, the eigenvalues are $0.99$, $0.99$. So the Jordan form is $\begin{bmatrix}0.99&1\\0&0.99\end{bmatrix}$. It is easy to check that its powers are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0.99^n&0.99^{n-1}n\\0&0.99^n\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so all entries go to zero.

Comment: Since $|\lambda|<1$ for matrix C, does that mean it is bounded? Or because it converges to the zero matrix it isn't bounded?

Comment: Yes, of course it is bounded. Each entry of $C^n$ will always be less than $1$.

Comment: My bad. The 1,2 entry is not always less than $1$. But it goes to zero, so it is bounded. Is goes to almost 37 before it starts decreasing to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix $B$ is the matrix of a rotation. So it's powers are easy to compute and are also a matrix of a rotation with coefficients bounded by $1$.